# Have Republican senators announced any plan(s) to question Hunter Biden?

Tags: united-states, senate

[May 13 news](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/05/13/senate-gop-moves-forward-with-hunter-biden-probe-schedules-subpoena-vote.html) were that

> The Senate Homeland Security and Governmental Affairs Committee, led by Sen. Ron Johnson, R-Wis., will hold a vote May 20 on whether to subpoena Blue Star Strategies, a firm that represented Ukrainian natural gas company Burisma Holdings when Hunter Biden was on its board.
>
> Austin Altenberg, a spokesman for the committee’s Republican majority, confirmed the upcoming vote to CNBC and provided a copy of the agenda for the May 20 meeting. [...]
>
> Altenberg in his own statement maintained that “the American people deserve to know the extent to which the U.S.-based, Democrat-led consulting company leveraged its connections within the Obama administration to try to gain access and potentially influence U.S. government agencies on behalf of its corrupt client, Burisma.”
>
> The majority’s statement said that Blue Star had not “fully responded” to prior requests for information. “This subpoena furthers the committee’s work to address the many unanswered questions about this effort and potential conflicts of interest. It is unclear why anyone would want to help Blue Star Strategies continue to hide what happened here.”

(Needless to say that Democrats have expressed their disapproval of this investigation and announced they'll vote against the subpoena. But they are in a 6:8 minority in that committee.)

I'm curious however if that or some other Senate committee has already questioned (e.g. via letters) Hunter himself. Or have they announced plans to do so?